# a testing of angular $broadcast method failed to get expected result

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i have a testing code to practice $broadcast, but these codes filed to get a expected result. the code is below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnzbV.png)

Comment: Post the code here, do not use images to show code

Comment: I think the broadcast event here happens before the receiver is ready.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved it.